# Nginx Django Gunicorn https site cannot be reached error

Tags: nginx, https, django, lets-encrypt, gunicorn

so I have a Django application, on a droplet running Ubuntu. I have nginx and Gunicorn and I am trying to setup https with Let's Encrypt, but I keep getting a "Site cannot be reached error".

Here is my nginx.conf :

```
upstream Tutorial2_prod{
    server unix:/var/test/proiect/Tutorial2.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    server_name juristnet.ro www.juristnet.ro;

    listen 443;  # <-

    ssl on;  # <-
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/juristnet.ro/fullchain.pem;  # <-
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/juristnet.ro/privkey.pem;  # <-
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;
        alias /var/test/proiect/favicon.ico;    
 }
     location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
        root /var/test/proiect;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/test/proiect/assets/;    
}
    location /.well-known/ {
        autoindex on;
        allow all;
        alias /var/test/proiect/.well-known/;
}
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/test/proiect/Tutorial2.sock;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}

server {
   listen  80;
   server_name www.juristnet.ro juristnet.ro;

        return 301 https://juristnet.ro$request_uri;

}
```

Output of `netstat -an | grep 443`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0     36 46.101.111.197:22       81.196.30.196:44356     ESTABLISHED
```

Gunicorn conf file:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling juristnet"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid admin
setgid root
chdir /var/test/proiect

exec /var/test/proiect/jurist/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/test/proiect/Tutorial2.sock Tutorial2.wsgi:application
```

Error logs are clear. Nginx -t returns no error. I can't figure out what is happening, i think it could be caused by the proxy_pass in the nginx conf. The domain is redirected correctly to https://example.com, but it shows nothing. Just that Connection Refused error. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is this config file on your website or a test box? https forwarding looks to be set up but isn't being applied. Since the .well-known folder is forwarded to https but there's no certificate set up I wonder if that's a catch 22. I would put a location for that directory on http aliasing that directory, which means you need your existing https redirect within another new location.

Comment: The certificate is setup. I obtained it from let's encrypt, and they could verify the files in well-known, so I am assuming the problem is not there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running nginx and the Gunicorn process as the same user & group may yield results.

Specifying the user and group in the nginx.conf by specifying:

```
user username groupname
```

Comment: tried that, still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You provide little indication as to Let's Encrypt invocation but I'm assuming webroot. In that case you need to serve challenges over port 80 so you need to have a location block for `.well-known` instead of a catch-all redirect.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific about that, I ended up adding the 443 server block inside the 80 one, so it's not https only. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Try adding a test file in `.well-known` and `curl` it. If it doesn't work, the issue is clearly NGINX and has little to do with Gunicorn.

Comment: It does work curling it. By the way, I don't know if it's relevant, but running nmap on localhost shows port 443 open, but running it for the server ip shows it is closed. But I am guessing a connection needs to be established for it to be open from the exterior, so I still think it has something to do with Nginx.  I opened another question with more info if you want to take a look : http://serverfault.com/questions/831160/nginx-refused-to-connect-to-port-443?noredirect=1#comment1061277_831160 Thanks anyway for your help :D